# resolving hashtags in textview

Tags: swift, uitextview

I'm setting the text on a textview and then calling this method of the UITextView extension in order to create links out of the words that are hashtags and mentions (Swift 3)

```
extension UITextView {
    func resolveHashTags(font: UIFont =  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)){
        if let text = self.text {

            let words:[String] = text.components(separatedBy: " ")

            let attrs = [ NSFontAttributeName : font ]
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes:attrs)
            for word in words {
                if (word.characters.count > 1 && ((word.hasPrefix("#") && word[1] != "#") || (word.hasPrefix("@") && word[1] != "@"))) {

                    let matchRange = text.range(of: word)
                    let newWord = String(word.characters.dropFirst())

                    if let matchRange = matchRange {

                        attrString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "\(word.hasPrefix("#") ? "hashtag:" : "mention:")\(newWord)", range: text.NSRangeFromRange(range: matchRange))
                    }
                }
            }

            self.attributedText = attrString
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is very simple. I have no way to create a link for something like this `"helloworld#hello"` simply because my word does not have a prefix of `"#"`

Another scenario I can't figure out is when the user puts multi hashtags together for example `"hello world, how are you? #success#moments#connect"` as this would all be considered 1 hashtag with the current logic when it should be 3 different links.

How do i correct? thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
func resolveHashTags(text : String) -> NSAttributedString{
    var length : Int = 0
    let text:String = text
    let words:[String] = text.separate(withChar: " ")
    let hashtagWords = words.flatMap({$0.separate(withChar: "#")})
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)]
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes:attrs)
    for word in hashtagWords {
        if word.hasPrefix("#") {
                let matchRange:NSRange = NSMakeRange(length, word.characters.count)
                let stringifiedWord:String = word

                attrString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "hash:\(stringifiedWord)", range: matchRange)
        }
        length += word.characters.count
    }
    return attrString
}
```

To separate words I used a string Extension

```
extension String {
    public func separate(withChar char : String) -> [String]{
    var word : String = ""
    var words : [String] = [String]()
    for chararacter in self.characters {
        if String(chararacter) == char && word != "" {
            words.append(word)
            word = char
        }else {
            word += String(chararacter)
        }
    }
    words.append(word)
    return words
}

}

   func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.attributedText = resolveHashTags(text: textView.text)
        textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red]
    }
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. Tell me if it worked out for you.

Comment: Almost got it perfected with this code!! @unniverzal it separates but starts from the beginning of the text....something missing from the length variable in the first fragment? Like the hashtags are at the end but links are being created at beginning of text... although the correct length ect

Comment: Do you mean texts starting with word and ending in hashtag? Example : "Hello#hello"  ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use a 3rd party library, you could try using [Mustard](https://github.com/mathewsanders/Mustard) (disclaimer: I'm the author).

You could match hashtag tokens using this tokenizer:

```
struct HashtagTokenizer: TokenizerType, DefaultTokenizerType {

    // start of token is identified by '#'
    func tokenCanStart(with scalar: UnicodeScalar) -> Bool {
        return scalar == UnicodeScalar(35) // ('35' is scalar value for the # character)
    }

    // all remaining characters must be letters
    public func tokenCanTake(_ scalar: UnicodeScalar) -> Bool {
        return CharacterSet.letters.contains(scalar)
    }
}
```

Which can then be used to match the hashtags in the text:

```
let hashtags = "hello world, how are you? #success#moments#connect".tokens(matchedWith: HashtagTokenizer())
// hashtags.count -> 3
// hashtags[0].text -> "#success"
// hashtags[0].range -> 26..<34
// hashtags[1].text -> "#moments"
// hashtags[1].range -> 34..<42
// hashtags[2].text -> "#connect"
// hashtags[2].range -> 42..<50
```

The array returned is an array of tokens, where each one contains a `text` property of the matched text, and a `range` property of the range of that matched text in the original string that you can use to create a link on the text view.